# Как сделать вместо 40 циклов 1?

Tags: python, list, for

Мой код складывает два соседних числа и делит на 2, в результате чего список каждый раз уменьшается на 1. Как сделать вместо 40 циклов один?

```
array = '1101111011010101110101010010011010100100'
array = [i + 1 for i in range(len(array)) if array[i] == '1']
count0, count1, count = 0, 1, []
print(len(array))
for i in array:
    count.append((array[count0] + array[count1]) / 2)
    count0 += 1
    print(count0)
    if count0 == len(array) - 1:
        break
    else:
        count1 += 1
```

Вот на простом примере:

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
a = [1.5, 3, 4.5, 5.5]
a = [2.25, 3.75, 5]
a = [3, 4.375]
a = [3.6875]
```

Это не среднее число списка - должно получиться 3.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В списке длиной N+1 (заметьте +1) нужно сложить числа с коэффициентами для K-го числа (нумерация с нуля) `С(N, K) / 2^(N)`, т.е.

```
Result = Sum(k=0..N){A[K]*C(N,K)/2^N} = 1/2^N * Sum(k=0..N){C(N,K)*A[K]}
```

где С(N, K) - [биномиальные коэффициенты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)

Например, для списка длиной 5 будут коэффициенты из 4-го ряда треугольника Паскаля `1,4,6,4,1`, разделённые на 16

```
def cnk(n, k):
    k = min(k, n - k)
    if k <= 0:
        return 1 if k == 0 else 0
    res = 1
    for i in range(k):
        res = res * (n - i) // (i + 1)
    return res

def freaksum(a):
    n = len(a) - 1
    return sum([a[k] * cnk(n, k) for k in range(n+1)]) / 2**n

l = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
print(freaksum(l))

>>> 3.6875
```

Здесь коэффициенты рассчитываются по ходу дела, но, имея предрасчитанный треугольник Паскаля, результаты для набора списков можно получать более оптимально.

P.S. Между прочим, всё это действие по большому счёту эквивалентно наложению Гауссова фильтра

для проверки:

```
def repsum(a):
    while len(a) > 1:
        b = []
        for i in range(len(a) - 1):
            b.append((a[i] + a[i + 1]) / 2)
        a = b[:]
    return a[0]

l = [1,2,3,4,8,9,10,13,14,15,19]
print(freaksum(l))
print(repsum(l))
```

Comment: Я считал вручную на это наборе чисел a = [1,2,3,4,8,9,10,13,14,15,19] и, получилось  9.06933595. этот код выводит 8.8310546875. Ошибка в коде или питон плохо считает? Если питон плохо считает как можно повысить точность(если можно)?

Comment: Питон вряд ли плохо считает. Добавил проверочный код