# Есть название числа ,у последовательности чисел в приведенном примере?

Tags: python, list

Список

```
f = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7]
```

брать среднее двух соседних чисел, пока не образуется одно число:

```
f = [1.5, 3, 4.5, 6]
f = [2.25, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
f = [2.875, 4, 5]
f = [3.4375, 4.5]
f = [3.96875]
```

Comment: О, даже одно число [в примере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1289588/2) изменено ;)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать вместо 40 циклов 1?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1289588/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-40-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-1)

Comment: Когда я смотрел в викепедии там была длинная и непонятная мне формула, как я не искал не видел алгоритма как у меня ,возможно это эквивалент понятного мне алгоритма, но есть ли название у этого числа, если сглаживать до последнего?

Comment: Вы прочитали ответ и часть P.S. в указанной ветке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это Гауссово усреднение (фильтрация)